# Using Aalto-xml forces to create new buffer for each XML

Tags: java, xml-parsing, stax, woodstox

I'm trying to setup Aalto-xml (Woodstox) in a Async environment, but having troubles figuring out how to do it correctly!

My flow is:

1. Pre-allocate 'AsyncStreamReader'

   `xmlInputFactory.createAsyncForByteArray();`
2. Receive XML stream from socket
3. Feed streamReader with data

   `streamReader.getInputFeeder().feedInput(bytes, 0, bufSize);`
4. Parse the different XML tags in a loop:

   `while (streamReader.hasNext()) {...}`
5. Upon Last `XMLEvent.END_ELEMENT` is parsed --> Invoke:

   `streamReader.getInputFeeder().endOfInput();`
6. Upon `XMLEvent.END_DOCUMENT` do:

   `streamReader = xmlInputFactory.createAsyncForByteArray();`
7. Upon `AsyncXMLStreamReader.EVENT_INCOMPLETE` --> Break the loop and wait for more data to feed the parser.

I do it like this although I know it's wrong because If I don't call:
'endOfInput()' then when feeding the reader with new buffer it throws an exception like I'm not done with the previous xml.

The point that fails me is that in order to get END_DOCUMENT you must call `endOfInput()` which closes the buffer so you cannot feed it with more input that comes from the socket...I'm stuck in a loop here !

How can I fix my flow?

Here is a Gist with the parser code:
https://gist.github.com/shvalb/ca9cd526aea31ccf280adf289e0991d7

Answer (score 0):

Wait for end of stream; 
 * InputStream.read() to returns -1, or
 * Stream is closed()) before calling endOfInput()

See this [example](https://github.com/skjolber/async-stax-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/skjolber/asyncstaxutils/XMLStreamFilterProcessor.java), it also optionally stops feeding input if the EVENT_INCOMPLETE is not returned.